# Regex - patern_match_all

Tags: regex

I am needing a regex that can extract only words that start with capital letters from a strings or all letters are capital
For example

```
$string= "Hola Mundo como Estas HOY"
```

From this text I need

> Hola, Mundo, Estas, HOY

Another thing is that I would like to show the first word only if its all capital
in that example the word Hola wont go.
I have this for the first

```
^[A-Z]+$
```

must start with capital and end with them, but how can I add more patterns?

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]+)
```

in PHP:

```
<?php 
$string = "Hola Mundo como Estas HOY";
$pattern = "/([A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]+)/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0]);
echo "</pre>";
 ?>
```

this will dump out an array of matches:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hola
    [1] => Mundo
    [2] => Estas
    [3] => HOY
)
```

to get this as a comma-delimeted string, you can then do:

```
echo implode(",", $matches[0]);
```

to return:

```
Hola,Mundo,Estas,HOY
```

Comment: great. how do I include áéíóú?

Comment: Just put them in the regex: 

   ([A-Z]{1}[áéíóúa-zA-z]+)

Comment: If you want to include single capital letters as well as capitalised words - you can use this regex:

([A-Z]{1}[áéíóúa-zA-z]+)|([A-Z]{1})

Comment: why did you use {1}? what is this for?

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern

```
\b(?:\p{Lu}+|(?<!^)\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?346k6)

`\b` is matching a word boundary

`\p{Lu}` is a Unicode code property that matches uppercase letters in all languages

`\p{Ll}` is a Unicode code property that matches lowercase letters in all languages

`(\p{Lu}+|(?<!^)\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)` is an alternation, matching either `\p{Lu}+` or `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+`.

`(?<!^)` Is lookbehind assertion that ensures that `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+` is only matching, if it is not at the start of the string

If you use this in php you have to set the modifier `u`

Comment: I try that and I have this

Comment: With that I have this Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => H
            [1] => M
            [2] => E
            [3] => HOY
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => H
            [1] => M
            [2] => E
            [3] => HOY
        )

)

Comment: I made the alternation a non capturing group, that should solve that problem.

Comment: How do I exlcude a set of words?

Comment: For example, this is my Text:

Comment: Detienen a nueve personas por abuso De menores Los en Artigas En MSP Súarez "hola como " lfkjglf .                                            I want to have the words with capital leters and exlude:De, Los,En  thanks